# How to intersect multiple IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, ienumerable

I don't understand why my variable `selected` doesn't contain the content of all the `TempX` variable. For example, in my case, the variable `TempX` containt one SuperObject but as soon as I reach the first intersect, it's lost and my View always show an empty list...

By the way, the blablabla.ToList() are real and complicated linq query. I put this to make it clearer.

Thanks and here is the code:

```
 public ActionResult Search(string q)
        {
            ViewBag.q = q;

            String[] strQueries = q.Split(' ');

            IEnumerable<SuperObject> selected = new List<SuperObject>();

            foreach (string str in strQueries)
            {  
                //Query 1
                IEnumerable<SuperObject> Temp1 = blablabla.ToList();

                //Query 2
                IEnumerable<SuperObject> Temp2 = blablabla2.ToList();

                //Query 3
                IEnumerable<SuperObject> Temp3 = blablabla3.ToList();

                //Query 4
                IEnumerable<SuperObject> Temp4 = blablabla4.ToList();

                selected = selected.Intersect(Temp1);
                selected = selected.Intersect(Temp2);
                selected = selected.Intersect(Temp3);
                selected = selected.Intersect(Temp4);
            }

            return View("Search", selected);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the code and seeing the results of each intersection as it happens?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to use `Union` instead of `Intersect`. Here's the difference, I think it's self explanatory:
[image: Union, intersection, difference comparison.]

Answer (score 0):

You are intersecting an empty list with Temp 1-4.  This isn't going to yield any results.

Edit:  To elaborate, an intersect gets all elements common to two collections.  Since the first collection you are intersecting is empty the result is always going tobe empty.  So the answer really depends on what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to find only elements common to all 4 lists?  if so do what BurundukXP said:

```
selected = Temp1.Intersect(Temp2);
selected = selected.Intersect(Temp3);
selected = selected.Intersect(Temp4);
```

Are you trying to get a unique list of all the elements in each list?  Do something like this:

```
selected.AddRange(Temp1);
selected.AddRange(Temp2);
selected.AddRange(Temp3);
selected.AddRange(Temp4);
selected.Distinct();
```